# Setting the host header in java httpClient

Tags: httpclient

I am trying to set the host header when using java httpClient. I have found that it can be done in apache httpClient using setVirtualHost. How can I do the same with the java httpClient.

Answer (score 0):

The Host-Header is automatically set if you send a request. The following program sends a `GET` request to `httpbin.org/headers` and displays the headers which arrived on server side.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(new URI("http://httpbin.org/headers"))
                .GET()
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.body());
    }

}
```

The output of this program is

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "0", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Http2-Settings": "AAEAAEAAAAIAAAABAAMAAABkAAQBAAAAAAUAAEAA", 
    "Upgrade": "h2c", 
    "User-Agent": "Java-http-client/11.0.2", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5e89b28a-7028ca70c49af58d120493b1"
  }
}
```

You can change the value of the `Host` field by defining another URI, e.g. if the URI `http://www.httpbin.org/headers` is used, then the value of the Host header field is `www.httpbin.org`.

The `Host` header however cannot be set individually. A set of disallowed headers is defined in class `jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils`.

```
private static final Set<String> DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET;

static {
    // A case insensitive TreeSet of strings.
    TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    treeSet.addAll(Set.of("connection", "content-length",
            "date", "expect", "from", "host", "upgrade", "via", "warning"));
    DISALLOWED_HEADERS_SET = Collections.unmodifiableSet(treeSet);
}
```